# How to disable Garbage Collection in GHC Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc

How can I disable GCs, or vastly decrease the frequency of GCs?

Like giving it an `+RTS` option for some huge heap or or allocation size maybe?

I want to see how my program behaves when no GCs happen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(With the help from carter in #ghc on freenode)

There is no switch to completely disable GC. Instead, use all of the following `+RTS` runtime options:

- Disable idle time garbage collection using `-I0`.
- Set the "nursery" == "allocation area" size to something very large, e.g. `-A100G`, as GC will only be done when the allocation area is full.

See https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8-latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html for a description of these options.

Be aware that you will run out of RAM quickly.

Comment: Well... _you_ might run out of RAM quickly but not everyone will. ;-).  Also you can eliminate copy-collect via mark-sweep, `-c`, switch to just one generation (`-G`), and lower the amount of free space requried (`-mN`).

Answer (score 1):

I had good results combining nh2 and Thomas's answers into

```
+RTS -I0 -A90G -G1 -m1 -RTS
```

I have 100 GB of RAM, so I thought `90G` was a good allocation area size.

I also used [`System.Mem.performGC`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/System-Mem.html) to manually trigger GC at appropriate points and [`GHC.Stats`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Stats.html) to keep track of how much time has been spent in GC.